# what do contract-first and contract-last mean?

Tags: web-services

I am doing some research on web services.  I have not written any web service but I am doing a small write up on them.

During my research I've come across terms **contract-first** and **contract-last**.

Can someone explain these two in an understandable form ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To expound on the answer by [Kaleb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899042/459391), **contract-first** is where you create the [WSDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language), and then you can create the implementation from this, and since the WSDL is your contract, this would be contract-first.

**Contract-last** is where the WSDL is created from the source code, or implementation, so it will most likely be generated by a tool rather than created by the developer.

**Update:**

For a nice explanation with code, in Java, you can look at [this explanation from the Spring Web Services 1.5 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/why-contract-first.html).

They will discuss the pros and cons, though they will be biased toward their approach (which is **contract-first**). Anyway, I think it is a nice explanation.

Answer (score 8):

*Contract-first* means you design the way your services are going to communicate with each other **before** you design the services themselves.

*Contract-last* is the other way around – you design how your service is going to work, then make one or more methods available as the interface for other services.