# Local WSDL vs downloaded remotely from server?

Tags: soap, wsdl

I was recently working quite a lot on SOAP web services and one question bothers me in that context. What would be better?

A. Get the WSDL and store it locally on client side and then only make calls to the service

- if server keeps backward compatibility the client will still work with the old WSDL even when server side provided new version (of service and WSDL).
- you are not able to get endpoint URL from WSDL so if service endpoint location has changed (but WSDL not) you need to reconfigure the client.
- no additional call to the server

B. Use WSDL location as remote resource (HTTP) and download WSDL each time client instance is created?

What are some pros and cons?

Comment: Note that many environments will be unable to use a dynamically-changed WSDL in any case.  I happen to think that's a good thing. If the service interface changes, not only will the clients need the new WSDL, they will need to be _tested_ with the service changes. Automatically updating the clients can give the illusion that there is no testing required.

Answer (score 4):

Which is better depends on your setup and your needs but personally I would prefer having the WSDL locally, inside the client for these reasons:

- no extra call to the server to get the WSDL (as you mentioned);
- if server keeps backward compatibility the local WSDL will still be OK to use (as you mentioned);
- if the service WSDL changes in an incompatible way and your client suddenly starts to fail you still have the old WSDL locally and you can compare it with the new one to see what's different.

The following point is usually not an issue:

> you are not able to get endpoint URL from WSDL so if service endpoint location has changed (but WSDL not) you need to reconfigure the client.

[The endpoint URL in the WSDL is not always correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992847/why-does-the-webservice-return-data-even-if-the-ip-address-in-the-wsdl-is-wrong) and even if it was, you normally have the WSDL accessible at the same URL as the service by just sticking a `?wsdl` parameter after it so if the location changes you won't find the service but you wont find the WSDL either. The service endpoint URL needs to be configurable in your client anyways.

Comment: Case is rare but valid :) I was prototyping usage of a service discovery and wsdls are stored there, and location points to proper one. Main goal was - client doesn't care where services are, only where ServiceDiscovery is. But the idea was abandoned because of other issues (mainly different authentication methods for services).