# how a REST client will generate its stub automatically witgout a WSDL file

Tags: rest, web, service, wsdl

I am new to Rest web service and while learning it a question strikes me,
In SOAP based web service, WSDL is act as a contract between client and service provider, so, Client will know how to interact with service provider by reading the WSDL file and create a client which is highly capable of interacting with service provider. To my understanding, in Rest web service we don't have WSDL so how a client will generate its stub automatically?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327018/creating-a-wadl-and-wsdl-in-java/ and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452750/why-the-slow-wadl-uptake

Answer (score 1):

In REST, clients are not generated automatically, in general. There is something called WADL, which is sort of "WSDL for REST", but it's not a standard yet and may never become a standard. But in general, all REST clients need to be created without the use of metadata from the service.